# ubuntu server does not get ip on restart

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, reboot, ip

i migrated a vm (virtual box) with ubuntu server installed to a new host. Now it always fails to setup the network on boot.
After reboot i always run `/etc/init.d/networking restart`. After this the server gets an ip.
Does anyone have a solution for this. I could just write the command in the boot script. However, this seems like worst practice.

Comment: Is this useful? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1988601 It says that "You need to change the network adapter on the VM to Bridged mode, it sounds like it is in NAT mode which is the default for VM's"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to enable to it during boot time.

check it's status,
`sudo systemctl status networking.service`

`Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)`

This is second line of status on my system,
It is showing `enabled; vendor preset: enabled`. The first enabled means that it is enabled at the start time. The `vendor preset: enabled` means it is automatically enabled when installed(from the vendor).

This will do the trick for you,
`sudo systemctl enable networking.service`